# How to compare a sonification to the original data set?

Tags: correlation

I have been working on a research project where my plan is to compare methods of sonification and their correlation to the original data set. My problem is that I have been unable to find a way to compare the raw data I made my sonification with to the end result. The raw data is just a list of numerical measurements and I have my sonification in the form of a .wav file. Are there any methods to do this? I apologize if this is not the most appropriate place to ask this, and would appreciate if I could at least be directed to a better place to ask this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your situation? I suspect this will require specialized knowledge from potential answerers. What are "sonification" and .wav files?

Comment: Sonification is the conversion of non-sound data into a sound file, typically for the purpose of analysis.  WAVE (.wav) is simply an audio file format.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method for direct comparison would be to go by ear. Maybe play your different sonification methods (all having the same length and relative loudness), and display the numbers as a visual graph as well. With auditory displays, it is sometimes helpful to provide a redundant visual display for people to better understand what they are listening to.

You could also create a block diagram to display the different mapping decisions behind each sonification strategy.